# List emptied after a function

Tags: python

I have a function in a program which requires me to organise a list in a specific order, however MyList is emptied after the function resolves? What is wrong with my function and how do I fix it?

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

def organizeList(li):
    finalList = []
    sortList = li
    sortList.sort()
    for x in range(len(li)):
         pop = sortList.pop()
         if len(finalList) % 2 == 0: 
             finalList.append(pop)
         else:
             finalList.insert(0, pop)
    return finalList

print(myList) # Returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(organizeList(myList)) # Returns [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2]
print(myList) # Returns []
```

Comment: You `pop`ped everything out of that list, so of course it is empty...

Comment: Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/1400623:

> the parameter passed in is actually a reference to an object

Your `sortList`, `li` and `myList` point to the same object that gets emptied by `sortList.pop()`
Fix this by [cloning/copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python) instead, for example: `sortList=li[:]`

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
pop = sortList.pop()
```

with

```
pop = sortList[x]
```

list.pop() deletes the 0th element of the list by unless provided an index such as list.pop(2) etc.

in your case you just have to index not delete the elements from the list.

Comment: I want to delete the last element of the list

Comment: to delete last element of the list you can sortList.pop(-1) using -1 the pop method will delete the last element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Python **never** does copy the objects you pass during a function call. Your list is passed by **reference** and **not by value.** So, when you do `sortList = li` and then `sortList.pop()` you are actually working on your original `myList` list (and this is **not what you want** since you are modifying it with a `pop()` later).

In order to circumvent that, **you need to make a copy of the list**, this is exactly what the `list()` function does.

Try the following code:

```
def organizeList(_li):
    li = list(_li) # Make an actual copy of the list.
    finalList = []
    sortList = li
    sortList.sort()
    for x in range(len(li)):
         pop = sortList.pop()
         if len(finalList) % 2 == 0: 
             finalList.append(pop)
         else:
             finalList.insert(0, pop)
    return finalList
```